# How to use an object inside an class member function in PHP

Tags: php, oop, pdo

I want to know how we could use a whole object inside an another object without using inheritance(if it is possible). if not how could we use PDO class with MySQL Database inherit with a class named abc having a default constructor. how could i use it manage to use PDO constructor value and abc constructor value at the same time?

here are the two objects

```html
<?php 
$pdo=new PDO('mysql:dbname=database;host=localhost','root','pwd');

class abc
{
  var $a, $b;
  function __construct($parm1, $pram2)
  {
    $this->a=$parm1;
    $this->b=$parm2;
  }

}


?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In PHP an object and a class are essentially the same thing. The `__construct` function is called when you create a new class object and you can pass arguments into the function at that time like so:

```
class abc {
    function __construct($dsn, $user, $password) {
        $this->pdo = new PDO($dsn, $user, $password);
    }
}

$my_class = new abc('mysql:dbname=database;host=localhost','root','pwd');
```

But I would do something like this to keep it simple:

```
class abc {
    function __construct() {
        $this->pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=database;host=localhost','root','pwd');
    }
}

$my_class = new abc();
```

Comment: thanks david for this answer... can you please tell me how can we do this in case of inheritance? When both class have there own default constructors, can i use a separate function to use taking parameters for PDO?

Comment: Both classes? I only see one class in this example. What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: i want accompolish this 
<?php
class abc implements PDO
{
function __construct($a,$b)
{
//same as above
}
function pdo_perameter('mysql:dbname=databse;host=localhost','root','pwd')
{
//coding that would put these parameters to PDO and i can access to all PDO Functions in this class
}
}

?>